# Setting textbox values in VBA for excel in a UserForm only works on every other attempt

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently building a macro that when you dobbeltclick a cell, it opens a userform with textboxes. I then populate the textboxes with data from the row the cell you clicked is in.

My problem is: 
When I dobbeltclick the cells in row 4 it opens a UserForm with blank textboxess.
If I then dobbeltclick another cell in that row it opens the UserForm with the cells filled out correctly.

Then if I dobbeltclick a cell in another row, it opens the userform with the data from the previous row.

Again, if I dobbeltclick another cell in the same row, it opens correctly.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

        If Intersect(Target, Range("N1:N200", "B3:O200")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Selection.Select
        currentRow = Selection.Row


        redigerskadeForm.Show

        redigerskadeForm.SagsNrTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.referenceTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.sagstypeComboBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.adresseTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.postTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.kontaktTextBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.tlf1Textbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.tlf2Textbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.mailTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.ansvarComboBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.opDatoTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.foDatoTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.statusComboBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.noteTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("o" & currentRow).value



End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Selection.select` good for? In a worksheet event you do not really need to refer to `Activesheet`. Reading suggestion for [userforms](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/), [default instance](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html) and [Userform1.show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

Comment: Reason for that is that on`Userforn.Show`code execution of the event is paused till you hide/destroy the form. Then the values are assigned to the controls on userform 8if still exists). So on first execution, userform opens ang gets displayedm, but no data is written.till it hides., So you see the values of first time on second execution, and so on., Add `Unload Userform after the show` (but just for testing) what destroyes the instance and you will so no data on all executions..

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to change the values before opening the form like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

        If Intersect(Target, Range("N1:N200", "B3:O200")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Selection.Select
        currentRow = Selection.Row

        redigerskadeForm.SagsNrTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.referenceTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.sagstypeComboBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.adresseTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.postTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.kontaktTextBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.tlf1Textbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.tlf2Textbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.mailTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.ansvarComboBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.opDatoTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.foDatoTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.statusComboBox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & currentRow).value
        redigerskadeForm.noteTextbox.value = ActiveSheet.Range("o" & currentRow).value

        redigerskadeForm.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: IMO even if you use the default instance of the userform a `With` and `End With` should be used.

Comment: To kep DRY (Don't repeat yourself), you should use a loop to set the controls and iterate through the columns/controls in that. That needs an assignment of of control to column, what can be done in serveral ways, (e.g control name contains the column as fu##suffix or use a tag or an array).. To avoid unwanted pausing in code, consider to use thecode from Userform, not sheet.